# VPN connection between 2 AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, rras

We have a setup where already AWS and Azure is VPN connected using a RRAS instance on AWS side.  Also On-Premise and AWS is connected through an AWS VPn gateway and an on-Premise Sonicwall FW with site to site tunnel.

This was all a single region network till now. But we now need to setup some servers in another region too. So I have following questions.

- Can one Windows server 2012 instance create 2 RRAS connections ?
- If above is possible, Is it possible to use the same Win 2012 RRAS server in region1 to create another RRAS connection and "pair" it with AWS VPN gateway in region2 ??
- What are the best possible (and cheapest) options for me to achive inter region connectivity and routing with current setup ?